# What data is stored in the index file of mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am recently working on better indexing concepts. as part of that, I am curious to know what is that stored in the index file(.MYI file) if that is a MYISAM table or the shared table space if that is an INNODB table..?

To give you more clarity,
**I know that when we create an index, the table will be re created updating the index filed or file. I would like to know what is the data used to update the index field..?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .MYI file is for a MyISAM table contains the table's indexes. And file has two parts- the header information and the key values.

[This](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM) explains in detail about internals of MyISAM and [this](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM#The_.MYI_file) about .MYI file

Comment: Links are expired!

Answer (score 1):

[index theory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

go to the link two know about index.